# Way to listen BigQuery table schema changes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm working on a Java app where I need to compare the data that I'm receiving from a MQ Topic with the Schema of a BigQuery table.
When the data has one field that no exists in the table I need to execute an Alter Table adding the column.
I already know How I can get the schema using the method getTable of BigQuery service, but it do a service call tô GCP.
I need to do this to every message because is a flow Very Dynamic.

Do someone knows if exist an way to configure a cache to this service or if exist an way to listen to schemas changes? In this way i could implement a cache lógic.

Thanks

An information if what i am looking for exista.

Comment: If the schema update is done by an `ALTER TABLE` DML statement, simply listen the logs and filter to catch all the alter table entry. Then create a sink to PubSub and like that you have an event (a message in PubSub) every time you have that log entry in Cloud Logging.